# View - Generate rows based on Column

Tags: mysql

Table 1

```
--------------------------------
Start    | End      | interval |
--------------------------------
08:00 AM | 10:00 PM | 60       |
--------------------------------
```

I want view something like below

```
---------------------------
SessionStart | SessionEnd |
---------------------------
08:00 AM     | 09:00 AM   |
---------------------------
09:00 AM     | 10:00 AM   |
---------------------------
.
.
.
---------------------------
07:00 PM     | 08:00 PM   |
---------------------------
08:00 PM     | 09:00 PM   |
---------------------------
09:00 PM     | 10:00 PM   |
---------------------------
```

What I want above is start time and end time is divided base upon interval(minutes). 
Can it be done?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `start` and `end` datatype? varchar or?

Comment: datetype, mostly in time